# Tomcat 7 Throws Intermittent 400 Errors

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm having an issue on my intranet servers with Tomcat 7.0.63.0 installed; Seemingly random users who access the website running on the server are getting a 400 Bad Request errors.

Sometimes this happens when users go directly to the website. Other times users can get to the site directly no problem, but navigating to a different page within the site throws the 400 error

We all use the same version of IE11. It seems clearing the browser cache & cookies resolves the issue, but there have been more and more reports of this 400 error that I couldn't possibly give everyone that instruction. I don't truly  believe this is a client side issue as we all have the same browser, but I could be wrong

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any kind of direction is very much appreciated!

TL;DR

- Random 400 Errors
- Tomcat 7.0.63.0
- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.29
- IE 11

Comment: What protocol are you using for the connector? Try switching to Http11NioProtocol if you are using a Http11Protocol one.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? i'm experiencing the same issue with tomcat 7.0.88 after upgrating from 7.0.47 to address a separate issue.

Comment: And now me too.  Tomcat 9 throws `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine` et al for stuff as simple as `GET / FRED/1.0`.  Given that Tomcat faces the Internet and is enterprise grade, I'd expect more resilience.  Strange...

Comment: Is that `400` generated by Tomcat? Or is there a possibility that is generated by something in front of it, e.g a TLS termination proxy?

And if it's generated on Tomcat, is there a stacktrace or application level log which tracks this error page generation?